# how to count back with a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while, counting

This is an example exercise to count backwards from 10 to 1. Print the numbers on the screen.

and this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
i=1
while( 11 > i ) {
document.writeln("<p>" + i + "</p>");
i--;
}
</script>
```

I don't know what mistake is in the code but the numbers didn't print on the screen.
Also, the browser took awhile to load and I had to stop it.
Could someone give an explanation so I can understand how to write this the correct way? Thank you.

Comment: have u tried `console.log("<p>" + i + "</p>")` ?

Comment: start from 10: `let i = 10;` and continue the loop until `i > 0`

Comment: and also try `while (0>i)` instead of `while( 11 > i )` and `i=10` instead of `i=1`

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understood you are trying to add the "p" tag with iteration number to the your document.
There are several mistakes in your code:

1. You did not specify type of the variable "i"
   In our example, "let" will be best choise.
2. Your while loop is endless because you are not reassigning "i" variable
   Your "i--" operation just took the number from variable, then subtracts 1 and does not use the result anywhere. You need to assign the result to another variable or, in this case, overwrite an existing variable
3. Also, the loop condition is not built correctly.
   The final result should look like:

```js
let i = 10;
while (i !== 0) {
  document.writeln("<p>" + i + "</p>");
  i = i - 1;
}
```